# In js fucntions what is it called when you add curly brackets and then end of a function?

Tags: javascript

What is it called when at the end of a function curly brackets, you type another set of curly brackets.

```
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Click!!!');
    }, {
    once: true
    });
```

Comment: use capture option of addEventListener, you can find API reference at:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

Comment: The comma is the function argument separator, the same as between `'click'` and `() => …`

Answer (score 1):

Those curly braces create an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), which basically just means a piece of data made up of name/value pairs (properties).

In this particular case, the object is being used as an options object. That is, it is being used to configure a function. The [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function knows how to change its behavior based on what you tell it to do with this object. If you do not provide the options object, it will use some default values. Thus, like most options objects, it is *optional*.

Think of it like this: if I ask you to go to the third floor of a building, you might take the stairs or you might take the elevator. But if I know the elevator is slow, I'll specifically tell you to take the stairs. The options object serves as these extra instructions.

Answer (score 0):

That is the third argument at the addEventlistener function. The curly braces just mean, that you're passing an object into it.